# How to fetch and display the data from the database?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-collection2

Am trying to fetch and display the items from my collection.
I created the template and gave it the design for each item. Here is the code:

```
<template name="list_products">

    {{#each applications}}
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                    <div class="caption">
                         <h4 class="pull-right">{{price}}</h4>
                         <h4><a href="#">{{title}}</a>
                                    </h4>
                                    <p>{{description}}</p>
                     </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

on the .js file, i created the applications that will return all the items in the collection

```
Template.list_products.applications = function(){
    Products.find();
}
```

then i called the template in the .html file

```
           {{> list_products}}
```

I got this error once i run "npm run start"

```
Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/js/jquery.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled
```

what am i doing wrong? any steps am missing here?

Comment: Is the problem that it's displaying nothing or the wrong data? If you open a console, what does `Products.find().count()` give you?

Comment: I guess your problem may be the `Template.list_products.applications` part. Try `Template.list_products.helpers.applications = function(){
    Products.find();
}`. I assume you have autopublish or already make your publications.

Comment: @DavidWeldon i got 3, the number of documents in the collection

Comment: @Oscar okay, trying it now

Comment: @Oscar didn't work. t don't have the autopublish and i didn't make the publication. i put my collection in /lib directory to be accessed by both client and server. Do i still need to make the publish and subscribe?

Comment: Are you using the Iron Router package

Comment: @StefanL19 yes am using it

Comment: I don't get you in the part of running "npm run start". Why don't you run your app using `meteor run`?. Can you post you collection and routes?

Comment: @Oscar because am using package.json in my meteor project which i have to use npm run scriptName to run :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it by using a helper.

```
    Template.list_products.helpers({
     applications:function(){
      return Products.find({});
      }
    });
```

Again you could iterate through the applications because it will return a cursor. It is possible also to `return Products.find({}).fetch();` 
But first try with the cursor in order to see if it works.

Comment: thanks it worked, accepted your answer. one question if you know the answer. How can i make every item clickable? i want to make the user goes to the item preview page one he click on it. :)

Comment: There a a few steps to make it clikable. First, make route which you want to use in order to diplay a single post usually it is : posts/{{_id}} and proceed further by doing its template. When you render the route set a session variable to this.params._id. And in this way you will be able to pull from the database a single entry by its id. I could not write the whole code here but follow these steps and see some examples.

Comment: I love SO when I see a question like this. ty both